# Binding RadioButton to Page property using IValueConverter

Tags: c#

I have problems binding a property to RadioButton using IValueConverter in WP8.1 app.
Here's my code.

in MainPage:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    private int radioValue;
    public int RadioValue
    {
        get { return radioValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value != -1)
            {
                radioValue = value;
                /*some important action*/
            }
        }
    }
...
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ...
    RadioValue = 1;
    this.DefaultViewModel["RadioValue"] = RadioValue;

}
```

then in RadioValueConverter.cs file:

```
class RadioValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (value is int)
            return Int32.Parse((string)parameter) == (int)value;
        else return parameter.Equals(value);
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (parameter == null || (bool)value == false)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (parameter is string)
            return Int32.Parse((string)parameter);
        else return parameter;
    }
}
```

finally in XAML:

```
...
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"

...

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:RadioValueConverter x:Key="RadioValueConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

...

<RadioButton
     GroupName="RadioValue"
     IsChecked="{Binding RadioValue, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource RadioValueConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            >
```

The problem is that the RadioValue set method is never called from RadioValueConverter, so it doesn't change its value and doesn't execute the tasks I need.
Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my code?
Thank you in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `DataContext` to an `ObservableDictionary`. When you try to bind to the property `RadioValue`, WPF reflection will look for `DefaultViewModel.RadioValue` instead of `DefaultViewModel["RadioValue"]`. WPF reflection will not look for `MainPage.RadioValue` because you changed the `DataContext`

Obviously `DefaultViewModel.RadioValue` doesn't exist on an `ObservableDictionary`.

You will have to replace the `ObservableDictionary` with your own class if you want to use it as a `DataContext`

Something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class that you can set as your DataContext
/// </summary>
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _radioValue;
   /// <summary>
   /// The RadioValue that your binding will find
   /// </summary>
   public int RadioValue
   {
      get { return _radioValue; }
      set
      {
         if ( value != -1 ) {
            _radioValue = value;
            /*some important action*/
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged event
   /// </summary>
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   /// <summary>
   /// Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed</param>
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

To set the `DataContext` to your own class, you can do it in the `Constructor` of `MainPage`:
`this.DataContext=new YourViewModel();`